# Looping in XML file

Tags: php, xml

```
<?php
$xml = "<Placemark>
<name>ED1YBY</name>
<description><![CDATA[145.750 MHz -600 kHz FM (RV60 - R6)<br>IN62IG<br>URE Ourense]]></description>
<styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
<Point>
<coordinates>
-7.281189,42.271212,0
</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
<name>ED1YBY</name>
<description><![CDATA[145.750 MHz -600 kHz FM (RV60 - R6)<br>IN62IG<br>URE Ourense]]></description>
<styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
<Point>
<coordinates>
-7.281189,42.271212,0
</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
";

$obj = new SimpleXMLExtractor($xml);

$name_array = array();
$description_array = array();
$coordinates_array = array();

foreach ($obj->name as $value1) {
$name_array[] = trim((string)$value1);
}

foreach ($obj->description as $value2) {
$description_array[] = trim((string)$value2);
}

foreach ($obj->Point->coordinates as $value3) {
$coordinates_array = trim((string)$value3);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>EXTRACTING DATA</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<th><h4 style = "width:300px; text-align:center">FREQUENCY</h4></th>
<th><h4 style = "width:140px; text-align:center">CALLSIGN</h4></th>
<th><h4 style = "width:140px; text-align:center">LOCATOR</h4></th>
<th><h4 style = "width:140px; text-align:center">LAT</h4></th>
<th><h4 style = "width:140px; text-align:center">LONG</h4></th>
<th><h4 style = "width:140px; text-align:center">SySop</h4></th>
</tr>

<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_array); $i++) {
echo "<tr style = 'text-align:center'>";
$notes = explode("<br>", $description_array[$i]);
echo "<td>".$notes[0]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$name_array[$i]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$notes[1]."</td>";
$latlon = explode("," , $coordinates_array);
echo "<td>".$latlon[1]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$latlon[0]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$notes[2]."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>

</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using SimpleXMLExtractor for the very first time. I wrote down such code which works perfectly in case there is just one Placemark element in the $xml variable.
If I added a second Placemark element in $xml (actually, 130 elements to be honest!) errors show up.
I read documentation about SimpleXMLExtractor but couldn't see and find a good solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have updated the code inserting a second placemarkers, instead of the whole 130 group. Such code breaks down when there are more than 1 placemark elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick search on php.net for SimpleXMLExtractor. It did not turn up any results.

Please replace this line:

```
$obj = new SimpleXMLExtractor($xml);
```

With this:

```
$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

The other issue is that you need a root XML tag. For example,

```
<placemarkers>
    <placemarker></placemarker>
    <placemarker></placemerker>
</placemarkers>
```

Also, copy and paste your XML into this http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ website to validate your XML.

Comment: You are welcome. The other day I ran your code with simplexml_load_string, I get plain text that looks like a table. Does the code you posted as a question have the 2nd placemarker you talked about? You may want to update your question to include a pastebin of your entire code. The more info, the better.

Comment: Correct, the output is a table filled with data extracted by the native function. I have added a second placemark in the code (which is just a copy/paste of the first) as example.

Comment: @ChemicalWeb Please see the updated response. You need to add a root tag. Also, make sure that your XML is well formatted.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, apparently no error messages this time. I have to fine tuning offsets for extraction, but this suggestion seems to work correctly!

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad I could help. Please do not hesitate to mark this answer as your best answer.